# Map not applied correctly

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a method of type:

```
HashMap[String, String]
```

And this variable:

```
var bestMatch = new HashMap[String, (String, Int)]
```

At the end of the method, I am trying to return this value:

```
 bestMatch.map((x, (y, count)) => (x, y))
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Cannot resolve reference map with such signature
```

Why am I applying it incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
 bestMatch.map(tuple => ( tuple._1, tuple._2._1))
```

You can't just put both arguments of the `(String,Int)` Tuple as your lambda function parameters. You need to use the tuple as one. If you write out your parameter types it becomes more clear maybe.

```
bestMatch.map((tuple: (String,(String,Int))) => ( tuple._1, tuple._2._1))
```

Also in your case it might be better to use `mapValues` since you're not doing anything with your key. Then you can use this:

```
bestMatch.mapValues(tuple => tuple._1)
```

Which is much more readable if you ask me. You could even go further and say:

```
bestMatch.mapValues(_._1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
bestMatch map {case (x, (y, count)) => (x, y)}
```